# Initiate a Factory Girl with a Class Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

Is there a way to override FactoryGirl's `:create` and `:build` methods with a class method?

For example, lets say I have a`Key` class and would like to create a Factory and '*generate*' some for my tests..

**models/key.rb**

```
class Key
    def self.generate!(attrs = {})
       # do some stuff
       create!(attrs.merge(encryption_key: key))
    end
end
```

**spec/factories/keys.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :key do
        primary false
    end
end
```

Instead of `FactoryGirl.create(:key)` - I would like to do something along the lines of `FactoryGirl.generate!(:key)`. I've tried experimenting with FactoryGirl's *custom methods* and *callbacks*  but not having any success.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add method generate! you need to call FactoryGirl.register_strategy

```
FactoryGirl.register_strategy :generate! , Generate
```

add the class Generate like this

```
class Generate 
 def association(runner)
    runner.run
  end

  def result(evaluation)
    evaluation.object.tap do |instance|
      instance.encryption_key = 'xxxx' if instance.has_attribute?(:encryption_key)
      evaluation.create(instance)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can define

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :key do
    primary false
 end
end
```

And call

```
FactoryGirl.generate!(:key)
```

Comment: This worked great! I was a bit confused by the docs concerning this and scrolled passed. I wasn't aware it was exactly what was needed. Thanks Abdoo.